# Android Awareness Snapshot API from IntentService got error 7503

Tags: android, intentservice, google-awareness

I got an IntentService that's work is to update the Weather data from Google Awareness API, and pass it back to the Wear companion.

I got the API key, got location rights, and also everything works when the code called from a simple Activity.
(in my mainActivity it is the same code, that in the IntentService, it is in the same package, in the same app).

Code:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
    }
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<WeatherResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull WeatherResult weatherResult) {
                    Log.w("a", "result:" + weatherResult.getStatus().toString());
                    if (weatherResult.getStatus().isSuccess())
                    {
                        Log.w("a", "Weather:" + weatherResult.getWeather().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }
    }, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }
    }).addApi(Awareness.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

SO, this code gives me the status ok, and passes correct weather data when It is in the Activity.

The code is ACL_ACCESS_DENIED.
Location is enabled, got the permissions.

In GoogleApiClient.Builder tried "this", "getApplicationContext", "getBaseContext", "getApplication". None of them worked.

Anybody got a solution?

Edit:
Here is the IntentService's relevant code. But it is similar to the upper code as I wrote:

```
public class SenderService extends IntentService {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private void handleActionWeather() {
    mGoogleApiClient  = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext(), new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            Log.w("a", "wsconn");              handleActionWeatherSupport(mGoogleApiClient);
        }
        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        }
    }, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Log.w("a", "wsconnfail:" + connectionResult.toString());
        }
    }).addApi(Wearable.API).addApi(Awareness.API).useDefaultAccount().build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
private void handleActionWeatherSupport(final GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplication(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<WeatherResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull WeatherResult wr) {
                if (!wr.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.w("a", wr.getStatus().toString());
                    return;
                }
                Weather we = wr.getWeather();
                Log.w("a", "got:" + we.toString());
            }
        });
}
...
```

}

Comment: Where is `IntentService`?

Comment: As I wrote that is similar, but copied there.

Comment: Have you tried with `Service`, not `IntentService`?

Comment: Not works with it too.

Comment: I know you said location is enabled, but is GPS enabled ("High Accuracy" or "Device only" in Location settings)?

Comment: It is High Accuracy, but it is not related. With the exact same options, from an Activity it works, and not works from an IntentService.